# Error: "ID does not reference a View inside this Activity" when updating gradle from appcompat:1.2.0 to appcompat:1.3.1

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-navigation-graph

I updated a component in a gradle file from:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
```

and started getting these errors:

```
Error inflating class fragment
ID does not reference a View inside this Activity
```

on this call from the startDestination fragment during the onCreateView:

```
navController = Navigation.findNavController(getActivity(), R.id.nav_host_fragment);
```

When I switch back to:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
```

The issue goes away. Has anybody managed through this update successfully? If so, what are the steps?

UPDATE

Requested XML from activity_main.xml

```
    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"
        app:defaultNavHost="true" />
```

Comment: It sounds like you are using the `<fragment>` tag in your Activity's layout. Do you see an error in that line asking you to use `FragmentContainerView`?

Comment: Can you share your XML for this fragment?

Comment: I am using a <fragment> as opposed to a FragmentContainerView but when I change that I get an error: "does not have a NavController set on..."

Comment: This will help you for sure : https://stackoverflow.com/a/69862620